# Nested parameterized routes with ui-router in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I believe I'm on the right track with these terms, "nested parameterized routes", but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

My objective is to create intuitive routes for my API, something like the following example:

```
/api/v1/project/list
/api/v1/project/1/item/list
/api/v1/project/1/item/1/edit
/api/v1/project/2/item/3/delete
```

It's relatively easy and clear how to setup project states, but not the item states within each project.

```
{
  state: 'project'
  config: {
    url:'/project'
  }
},
{
  state: 'project.list'
  config: {
    url: '/list'
  }
},
{
  state: 'project.detail'
  config: {
    url: '/:project_id'
  }
}
```

It's not clear to me where to go from there so that items are relative or nested within projects.

Comment: Just a followup, $stateParams will receive params from the abstract state and others.  So, this, in item routes, gets me closer:
{
  state: 'item'
  config: {abstract: true, url: '/project/:project_id/item'}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll assume you have a REST api (based on your example containing `/api/v1`) which you want to expose/parallel as a UI.  I'll assume you want to allow the user to drill down some hierarchical data model.

---

### Choices!

There are many ways you could organize your states, for this drill-down list/details pattern.  None is the "correct" way, but some are probably better than others.  I will highlight two approaches that I've used:

#### Sibling states for list and details

One approach is to keep the "item list" states and "item details" states as siblings.  This is what you did with `project.list` and `project.details`.    This approach can be seen in the [UI-Router Extras Demos](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/dsr/index.html#/) source code.

When taking this approach

- you must take care to move the user from the list state to the detail state when drilling down.
- This approach has the benefit of easy-to-understand nesting of UI-Views.  The ui-view for the detail view *replaces* the ui-view for the list view, when drilling down, because you are navigating to a sibling state.
- Your choice whether or not the detail for an entity *also retrieves the list of sub-entities* (does the detail for a project also show the items list for that product?)

States:

- `projectlist` // template plugs into parent ui-view
- `projectdetail` // template plugs into parent ui-view, replacing `projectlist`
- `projectdetail.itemslist` // template plugs into parent ui-view (`@projectdetail`)
- `projectdetail.itemdetail` // template plugs into parent ui-view (`@projectdetail`), replacing `itemslist`

#### Details state as a substate of List state

Another approach is to make the detail state a child of the list state.  This is organized similar to your REST routes.

When taking this approach

- States hierarchy closely resembles the REST routes being exposed
- Drilling down is simple and intuitive
- You must manage the visual display of list/detail.

  - When drilling down from list state to the details substate, you probably want to hide the list.
  - We use named views, and absolute naming in order to *replace* the parent list state's template with the template for the the detail state.  This is called "view targetting".

States:

- `top` // theoretical parent state
- `top.projects` // lists projects.  Plugs into parent ui-view (`@top`)
- `top.projects.project` // details for project.  Its *named view* targets the **grandparent** ui-view (`@top`), replacing the template from `top.projects` list state.
- `top.projects.project.items` // lists items.  Plugs into parent ui-view (`@top.projects.project`)
- `top.projects.project.items.item` // details for item.  Its *named view* targets the **grandparent** ui-view (`@top.projects.project`), replacing the template from `top.projects.project.items` list state.

---

Here's an example of using named view targeting to accomplish the second approach:

```
$stateProvider.state('top', {
  url: '/',
  template: '<ui-view/>',
});

$stateProvider.state('top.projects', {
  url: '/projects',
  resolve: {
    projects: function(ProjectsRoute) { 
      return ProjectsRoute.getProjects(); 
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, projects) { $scope.projects = projects; },
  template: '<li ng-repeat="project in projects">   <ui-view/>'
});

$stateProvider.state('top.projects.project', {
  url: '/:projectid',
  resolve: {
    project: function(ProjectsRoute, $stateParams) { 
      return ProjectsRoute.getProject($stateParams.projectid);
    }
  }
  views: {
    '@top': {
      controller: function($scope, project) { $scope.project = project; },
      template: 'Project details: {{ project.name }}   <a ui-sref=".items">view items</a>  <ui-view/>'
    }
});

$stateProvider.state('top.projects.project.items', {
  url: '/projects',
  resolve: { 
    items: function(ItemsRoute, project) { 
      return ItemsRoute.getItemsForProject(project.id); 
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, items) { $scope.items = items; },
  template: '<li ng-repeat="item in items">   <ui-view/>'
});

$stateProvider.state('top.projects.project.items.item', {
  url: '/:itemid',
  resolve: { 
    item: (ItemsRoute, $stateParams) { 
      return ItemsRoute.getItem($stateParams.itemid); 
    }
  },
  views: {
    '@top.projects.project': {
      controller: function($scope, item) { $scope.item = item; },
      template: 'Item details: {{ item.name }}'
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! That's a very thorough, detailed answer!  Thank you.

Comment: This great thank you! Curious though, where would a "search" fit into place here? top.projects.search then top.projects.search.results?

Comment: A search state is essentially the same thing as the list states in my examples.  I would probably not add a search.results state either, only a single search/list state (which has search parameters), and retrieves/displays the search results.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentleman. Thanks for this. I was missing the @top part, so my transitions were happening, but I wasn't getting a refreshed UI.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Github Wiki, the [Abstract States](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states) is enough.