# best practice/architecture to combine multiple js components in a spa

Tags: javascript, architecture, web-component

I would like to have the following architecture for a single page application:

1. each page or a widget can be an independent reusable module (reusable for this project however it might be used on others as well)
2. there will be a core application that will use all those external modules. the core application will be able to communicate with the modules and vice versa.
3. each module can be written in any technology (react, angular, vanilla)
4. each module should be deployed independently (something like dynamic-lazy-loading)
5. the core app should be responsible for the config of the modules (api urls etc)

I have not been able to think about a good way of achieving everything i stated nor find anything on google.. but i might be missing the keyword for such architecture.

Any ideas, best practices or just some relevant input? thanks!

Comment: [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) with [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router) and a restful approach seems like a good starting point. The subject is touched upon in this question: [nested-parameterized-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662148/nested-parameterized-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs)

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Thanks for the response but please notice that i wrote that each module should be able to be written in any language. i'm trying to find a way not to be handcuffed to any client-side framework. couldn't see anything relevant in the url you sent me

Comment: Any SPA needs a routing controller. Angular just happens to have a particular strong one, but that doesn't bind you to Angular controllers. You could use EmberJS' router or really any router on the internet as long as it is restful. That way you have the means to make unique requests that can activate different scripts. fx. a route to `/projects/` could create a `React` list of projects, whereas as a route to `/projects/:id` could activate some jQueryUI script to handle that specific project.

Comment: If you want to be framework independent, then you can use this little library: [Routie](http://www.javascripting.com/view/routie).

Comment: If you don't want to be framework-dependant... use vanilla Javascript or vanilla Web Components to build your core app (sorry for the tautology :-)

Comment: using different code bases in the same project is not so much the question as how to be able to manage multiple type of projects while been able to use them in different projects. for example - creating different repos for each module so i will be able to use them in any project (something like embeding) and been exposed to the modules interface. the perfect solution would also give me the ability to use those modules independently. for example, i was thinking about event-based interface. a nice example, but not so updated would be this thing i found - http://www.scaleapp.org

Answer (score 0):

after researching this subject bit more, the architecture that i think that will match my requirements is based on web-components (can read more about it here - http://webcomponents.org/ and would recommend using a library like polymer).
the advantage of a web-components is that they can hold everything they need in them (html,css,ajax requests, basically anything that can be in a html document) and using shadow or shady dom imply those components into the document just like we would have done once with iframes.

by using this architecture, you will be able to migrate your components without caring about the wrappers technology (angular 1/2,react, knockout, vanilla js etc). for example, in order to use it in angular, we just wrap a component with a directive and thats it.
the other bonus is that you can even host those components in different servers and therefore deploy them separately.